# Blurred Pictures

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

The answer is... well, you'll notice it.

---

[image]

Hint1

> S..m...y

Comment: I don't know if anyone made some progress already, but if you haven't then hint1(a word) should guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What are we looking at here? Art? No!

> **FAMOUS EQUATIONS**!

First:

> Note that all of the shapes in the two separate series exhibit reflective *symmetry* (Hint 1). And there is a way to transform them into two sets of characters:
>
>  [image: Symmetry removed from image]
>
>  Together, these characters form well-known equations from the realms of physics and mathematics:
>
>  [1.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence) E = MCC (i.e. $E$ $=$ $mc^2$)
>
>  [2.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) -1 = E<sup>i*pi</sup> (i.e. $-1$ $=$ $e^{i\pi}$)

What next? Well note that:

> Both of the equations we have just found are connected very closely to specific individuals - the first being formulated by [Albert Einstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein) and the second being named after [Leonhard Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonhard_Euler).
>
>  Armed with this, we can then spot that these individuals' first initials can be found in the next diagram above the period and their surnames can be spelled out in order along the and down rows of the section beneath the period:
>
>  [image: Spelling out the scientists' names]
>
>  i.e. **A.EINSTEIN** and **L.EULER**.

Finally:

> If we divide the last grid in half and highlight the cells corresponding to the previously found patterns for A.EINSTEIN (left-hand side) and L.EULER (right-hand side), we spell out the words **FAMOUS EQUATIONS**!
>
>  [image: Final answer derivation]

Comment: Well done! :) You might wonder why I didn't use a "gjb" vafgrnq bs na rkgen "P". Ohg V jnf 100 gung gung jbhyq'ir orra n fgebat tvirnjnl (abg bayl vf vg rnfvre gb fcbg guna gur erfg bs gur punenpgref, ohg vg'f nyfb va n fdhnerq cbfvgvba).

Comment: @Prim3numbah That probably would have been too much of a giveaway, particular since it would have made a highly irregular shape also... Out of interest, have I missed anything re the title? I wasn't sure if there was an additional significance or if it's just that the squares containing letters resemble the blurred pictures' squares...

Comment: No, it was just me who weren't able to come up with a fitting title without giving away too much info.